# How does cmake print the path of the header file of the library the project depends on?

Tags: cmake, ctags

I want cmake to output the path of the header file of the library that the project depends on, and give it to ctags to generate tags.

I have tried to generate tags of all header files of the system directly: `ctags -R /usr/include`, but the size of the generated tags file is 190MB, which is too large.

For example, if libcurl is used in the project, then let cmake output `/usr/include/curl`, and then ctags can `ctags -R /usr/include/curl`.

I looked at `cmake --help`, but didn't find what I was looking for. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Library does not depend on header files. Source files depend on header files.

Comment: @KamilCuk Maybe my statement is not clear. For example, when I use libcurl, I need a libcurl.so file, but I usually also include curl/curl.h in the project so that I can use libcurl, a third-party library. What I mean is that I want cmake to output all the relevant header files of the third-party libraries used in the project. This allows ctags to index these files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate compile_commands.json. Parse compile_commands.json, extract all `"command":` keys, extract all `-I<this paths>` include paths from compile commands, interpret them relative to build directory. `sort -u` the list.

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1 ...
$ jq -r '.[] | .command' "$builddir"/compile_commands.json |
     grep -o -- '-I[^ ]*' |
     sed 's/^-I//' |
     sort -u |
     ( cd "$builddir" && xargs -d '\n' readlink -f ) |
     sort -u
```